# Prototypal inheritance causes shared references

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm want to understand how and why are prototypes useful in Javascript. After I thought I knew what was going on, I stumbled with the fact that a prototype is just an object and can't be "shared" by many objects in the way I thought. Let me elaborate with an example:

```
var SpritePrototype = {
    img: null,
    pos_x: 0,
    pos_y: 0,

    draw: function(context2d) {
        /*do stuff with the canvas
          using "this" to refer to 
          the object this method is 
          being called on*/
    },
    //Some more member functions...
}
```

From the concept of "objects inheriting from objects" that's usually advocated with prototype-friendly Javascript, I thought I could just do:

```
var player = Object.create(SpritePrototype);
```

But it turns out this approach is flawed, because the non-function fields will be the ones from SpritePrototype, as player's prototype is exactly SpritePrototype. That means I can't create more objects from that prototype or the non-function fields will get all mixed up.

So what's the point in Object.create, and more important, what would be the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do? That is, how can I make "player" get a copy of the fields and inherit the functions from its prototype?

Again, I'm interested in doing things the way they're intended to be. I can always simulate inheritance by hand or skip it altogether. The point of my question is to understand prototypes and how and when they are useful, especially in my specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property values on prototypes are shared initially, but stop being shared when that property on an instance is written (assigned) to. At that moment, the instance gets its own version of the property.  So it is not entirely correct to say the value is "shared". It is shared only up to the point in time at which the property on the instance is assigned to.

```
var SpritePrototype = {
    img: 'img1'
};
var sprite1 = Object.create(SpritePrototype);
var sprite2 = Object.create(SpritePrototype);

sprite1.img = 'img2';            // does NOT affect prototype or sprite2
console.log(sprite2.img);

< "img1"
```

When `img` is referenced, its value is taken from the prototype. However, when `img` is **written** to, a new property is created on the instance to hold the new value, and used from then on.

The only way to change the property value on the prototype is to do so explicitly:

```
SpritePrototype.img = 'img3';
```

This will change `img` for all instances which have not yet defined their own local version of `img` by assigning to it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What you're saying is indeed correct. But I wouldn't say my example was entirely incorrect because of that. Anyway the undesirable side effect of doing that is that img is then both in sprite1 and in the prototype, so the property ends up being created twice. (EDIT): Or is this the intended way of using prototypes? Some sort of a "copy-on-write" mechanism? I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere else before.

Comment: It not an "undesirable" side-effect; it's a desirable one. You would not want to share a mutable property among instances (unless it's a "class-level", aka "static" property). On the other hand, if you don't need an instance-level version of the property, there's no need to keep one.

Comment: Prototype inheritance relies on links. When you create an object based on a prototype, unless you explicitly declare values on the new object, all of its methods and properties basically act as pointers to the prototype object. If you want to actually copy the properties - as in, set up a default object state - there are different ways to do that.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Actually, that is incorrect, as a bit of experimentation would show, including the example I show in my answer. The assignment to `sprite1.img` **does not** follow a "pointer" to the prototype and set the value of `img` on the prototype; it sets a value of `img` **on the instance**. Try it out.

Comment: @torazaburo That's not what I meant. I meant the behavior if you didn't actually do the assignment - that's what I meant by "unless you explicitly declare values on the new object". Before the assignment, `sprite.img` would refer to the property on the prototype.

Comment: @Setzer22: It's not copy-on-write. It's just how pointers/references work in any programming language. `Object.create()` makes a shallow copy of an object. Maybe you haven't fully realized the implications of a shallow copy. Think hard on what that means.

Comment: @slebetman I understand shallow copy and pointers at this level. I just wanted to point out that despite not being actual "copy-on-write", the concept is pretty similar. The value is stored only once for every "instance" until it's written, then a local copy is created but the others are not modified.

Comment: @torazaburo You're right, I was wrong in thinking about this as an undesirable side-effect, it's actually quite useful. Thank you all, this has helped me understand prototypes, and what does "differential inheritance" mean.

Comment: @Setzer22: No, that's not what happening. Forget about copy-on-write. Think pointers. A new object is created by creating all new pointers (they are actually created) initialized to the same value as the old object. But remember what it means when two pointers have the same value: they point to the same object. Also remember what it means for you to assign a pointer a new value: it points to a new object. Shallow copy works this way for all programming languages. Javascript is not special.

Comment: @slebetman Yes, sorry, I got too excited with that COW idea. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is, that you had defined "static" members in terms of object oriented design. Everything in protoype section is shared between objects. Function doesn't get actually copied to newly created object, but it is called with proper "this".

You should initialize your variables in constructor, like this

```
function Sprite(...) {
    this.img = null;
    ...
}
```

Then for subtype you should use Object.create to create a prototype to inherit its methods, so

```
Player.prototype = Object.create(Sprite.prototype);
```

And finally, you may call parent constructor to initialize the variables

```
function Player(...) {
    Sprite.call(this, ...);
}
```

PS. Constructor should be before Player.prototype assigning.

PPS. For more info see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Right, I understand. What's bugging me is why do people keep advocating the use of Object.create as a replacement for constructor functions. I've read many articles on the topic and all seem to conclude the constructor+new syntax should be left out and replaced by Object.create alone. Here you seem to be mixing both...

Comment: Not getting this answer. First, the OP was not asking about creating subtypes. Second, he presumably knows how to use `new` on a constructor function; he was asking about an **alternative** pattern, namely how to create objects using `Object.create`. Finally, he isn't worried about functions/methods; he's interested in non-method properties and how they behave.

Comment: @Setzer22 Those who advocate avoiding `new` entirely and using `Object.create` instead still need an initialization step if there are any (per-instance) object properties, e.g. `Object.create(Foo); Foo.init()`. (Some libraries create an alternate way to do this, e.g. `Foo.new()` which would call `Object.create()` internally.) Personally I think just using `new` works fine and I don't buy the arguments against it...you can still think prototypally either way.

Comment: As to inheritance, that's another matter...there are a couple distinct advantages of using `Object.create` specifically when extending a prototype, e.g. `SubType.prototype = Object.create(ParentType.prototype)` instead of `SubType.prototype = new ParentType()`. The main advantages are: (1) It works even if `ParentType` has required constructor parameters, (2) It helps to quickly detect the error if you call the parent constructor from the child constructor, since all the parent properties will be undefined until it is called (whereas if you had used `new` they'd be defined already).

Comment: And (3) (arguably the most important): If the `ParentType` constructor does something like this: `this.foo = []`, then by doing `Object.create(ParentType.prototype)` you avoid having a single copy of `foo` unintentionally shared among all instances of `SubType`.